# How "much" non-injective is a continuous map from the Möbius strip to the real plane?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

We all know that there exists no injective continuous map from the Möbius strip $M$ to the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, I am interested in quantifying this non-injectivity when we let $M$ be given as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, more precisely,

$$M=\{\varphi(v,u)\}_{v\in[-1,1],\;u\in[0,2\pi)}$$

where $\varphi(u,v):=\left[\left(1+\frac{v}{2}\cos\frac{u}{2}\right)\cos u,\;
\left(1+\frac{v}{2}\cos\frac{u}{2}\right)\sin u,\;\frac{v}{2}\sin\frac{u}{2}\right]$.

In particular, let $F:M\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be continuous. Is it true that there exists some constant $c>0$, independent of $F$, such that

$$F(x)=F(y)\;\;\text{for some}\;\;x,y\in M\;\;\text{with}\;\;|x-y|>c$$

?

Put it another way, I am asking whether the infimum below is positive or null,

$$\delta(M,\mathbb{R}^{2}):=\inf_{F\in\mathcal{C}(M,\mathbb{R}^{2})}\;\;\sup_{x\in M,\;y\in F^{-1}(x)}\;|x-y|.$$

For instance, for the unit sphere $S^{2}\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$, by the Borsuk-Ulam theorem we know that $\delta(S^{2},\mathbb{R}^{2})=2$, since every continuous map $S^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ fails to be injective at two **antipodal** points.

My guess is that $\delta(M,\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is also positive, but I am not able to prove. My intuition tells me that for any $F\in\mathcal{C}(M,\mathbb{R}^{2})$ there exists a point $x$ on the boundary $\partial M$ and a point $y$ on the middle line $\ell:=\{\varphi(0, u)\}_{u\in[0,2\pi)}$ such that $F(x)=F(y)$. The idea comes from the fact that, regardless of $F$, both $F(\partial M)$ and $F(\ell)$ are closed loops in the plane, but I couldn't proceed any further from here...

If you have any ideas please let me know!